# http://www.winpcap.org/ alternative

Tags: sockets, networking

Does anyone know an alternative for this?

I need a way to keep track of which websites (urls) a user is visiting, without depending on the browser (IE, FF, Chrome, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, in a workplace? We used to have a Linux box at the edge of the intranet, checking all outgoing traffic and logging every site every internal user visited.

Comment: OK, well in that case: you don't need winpcap, but you DO need to put the NIC driver in promiscuous mode in order to see what the traffic is doing. There must be other libraries you can use, or write the low-level code yourself. I rarely develop on Windows, so my knowledge is really dated in this area.